# running an existing system based on i686 Centos 6 on a 64 bit architecture

Tags: linux, centos, 64-bit, linux-kernel, cpu-architecture

I want to run an old Centos 6 based program (i686) on my Core i5 CPU but it doesn't seem to work although I have enabled virtualization. It's a pretty complex system with lots of software libraries that I might need to link and I am trying to avoid rebuilding and installing from scratch. 
is there any way to do so? The image currently runs on a Core2Duo CPU.
Here's the situation:
The image was cloned using one of [these](http://my.orico.cc/goods.php?id=4836)

I have tried the following :

1. I put the cloned image on my core i5 PC and it didnt boot. Keyboard lights started to flash. I suspect that it is a kernel crash.
2. I used the same cloned drive on a Core2Duo PC and it was working prefectly fine.

I want to run the same image on my core i5 (x86_64)

Comment: Go into the BIOS/UEFI menu and turn on CSM (compatibility Support Module) or "Legacy BIOS" options if available.  Chances are that your old system was BIOS based and the new one uses UEFI. This almost certainly has nothing to do with virtualisation, which is for running virtual machine software such as VirtualBox or VMWare or similar.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for the clarification. Legacy support is enabled. VT-x is enabled. I cant find CSM though. What do you suggest I do to run that image ?

Comment: How are you trying to "run that image"? Is it an image created by backup software or is it simply a hard disk with centos installed? Is this a new hard drive that you copied? Did you clone the disk? If so, what software? Did you clone all the partitions? What are you actually doing? What have you tried? Your question is currently very unclear about what you have and what you are doing. You can [edit] your question to add more detail.

Comment: @Mokubai I have edited the question. I hope it clears what I want to do

Comment: Possibly the old kernel on the CentOS system disk fails to recognize some essential hardware element on the new hardware, like the AHCI SATA controller. As a result, it fails to find the root filesystem and crashes. It would be important to describe what happens on the screen at the time of crash: will the system reach the GRUB boot menu, or not? If it does, what messages - if any - appear just before the crash? If there's just the CentOS boot logo, press Esc (or edit the boot entry in GRUB to remove the `rhgb quiet` boot options temporarily) to see the diagnostic messages.

Comment: @telcoM I will try that and post the log by tomorrow.

Comment: this is the error I get when I run it on my system. [link](https://imgur.com/a/upM9gbS)